# Como contanerar la primera letra del nombre y apellido para formar un E-mail

Tags: mysql

les quiero consultar como puedo formar el correo de los empleados concatenando la **primera letra del nombre** **con el primer apellido** y la **cadena literal ‘@miempresa.com’** (tomando en cuenta que los correos se escriben con letras minúsculas).

Estoy armando la siguiente sintaxis:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName
and CONCAT(nombre, ' ' , apellido)
LastName, SUBSTRING(FirstName, 1, 1) AS Initial  
from employees
```

Sin embargo no logro poder listar el E-mail, debería arrojar por ejemplo ndavolia@miempresa.com

Answer (score 3):

Con la función left obtienes el primer carácter de tu campo deseado

Ejemplo:

```
select EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, CONCAT(LEFT(FirstName, 1),LastName,'@miempresa.com') as email from employees
```

con minúsculas las primeras letras

```
select EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName,CONCAT(LEFT(FirstName, 1),CONCAT(LCASE(LEFT(LastName, 1)), LCASE(SUBSTRING(LastName, 2))),'@miempresa.com') as email from employees
```

todo en minúscula

```
select EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, LCASE(CONCAT(LEFT(FirstName, 1),LastName,'@miempresa.com')) as email from employees
```

puedes utilizar también la función  `LOWER` en vez de `LCASE`

Comment: Mil Gracias y en el caso de poder colocar las dos primeras letras del correo en minúscula (Ya que las arroja en mayúscula) que podría utilizar??

Comment: los protocolos para envío de email no validan el case de los username.

Comment: ya he actualizado la respuesta para lo de las primeras letras en minusculas